# Hard counterexample to the fact that outer measure is additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

My question is very short: does there exist a couple of sets $A,B\subset[0;1]$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, but $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=1$? Here $\mu(\cdot)$ is outer measure.

It's easy to construct disjoint $A,B$ such that $\mu(A)+\mu(B)\ne\mu(A\cup B)$ as a kind of Vitali set, but such an example doesn't answer my question. Of course, $A$ and $B$ have to be not measurable.

Comment: Google can be a valuable research tool. A search for "nonmeasurable set and complement both have full measure" turned up paragraph 134D in Measure Theory Vol. 1 by D.H. Fremlin that answers your question in the affirmative.

Comment: @UmbertoP. very nice, thank you!